# SlickGrid - get value of a cell in the first column of altered row

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I've got a SlickGrid table with a first column that contains an ID value.  If I change any value in the table I'd like to get the value of the first column on the row that was edited.

I've been able to get the row index, but I'm now really stuck on how I would get the value of the first column.

```
 grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function(e, args) {
            //Identify the name of the column where a value was changed.
            var dataString = grid.getColumns()[args.cell].name
            alert(dataString);

            //Now identify the index of the row that was changed.
            var rowIndex = args.row;
            alert(rowIndex);

           //Return the value of the first column in this row.
           //Stuck...:(
           var firstColumnValue = ???
           alert(firstColumnValue);
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

```
var firstColumnValue = rows[args.row][grid.getColumns()[0].field];
```

This does exactly what I need.